# Create website with Python without using Django

Tags: python

I need to create a website using python but without Django or any other framework, since the website I need to create ts very custom (at the back-end level specially) like having a dashboard after login and stuff like that.

I want to know what are the best practices and/or tutorials that can help me in such a situation.

Comment: Django is not a CMS, it's a framework, this means you can develop any kind of web application as you like!

Comment: If you don't want to use django or any other framwork, the you're left with [cgi](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html). Good luck with that. But I would say that you don't know what django is. Learn about it, because it seems that django could do a lot for you according to what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Ali Issa If for some reason you dont want any frameworks, the starting point is - Print out your html from a python script.  Literally - print("<html>..... </html>").  In between you can process the dynamic texts and print them.  For python to be interpreted your user click a python link, the server (say apache) httpd.conf file needs to be modified to 'execute' python like perl etc.

Answer (score 1):

I began to work with Django 3 months ago in a company. In my opinion this framework is very useful because you avoid to write a lot of HTML code and came with a lot of tools to automate the creation of many parts of the web and the database. Django allows you to use different databases.

I recommend you to visit [Django Website](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/) and see the overview and the installation. The difficulties for the beginners are to understand the use of views,templates,urls... but in the web site you have a 6 steps tutorial that make a very good introduction, anyways you must get some more information like this [Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter01.html) but is almost the same than the tutorial but more extense.

I didn't work with Python until I began to use Django, and I have to say that now I love the dynamism of Python, is fast and easy to understand.

I hope this can help you a little

Comment: I did a website with Django and I finished the tutrorial, I know it is super great, but what i need is very custom "which isn't recommended by the django team to change that much", that's why I am looking for an alternative

Comment: What kind of customization do you want to do ?

Comment: I need to create a dashboard once the user had logged in (number of comments today, views, articles), also I need some other functionalities

Comment: Im programming with Django, and the web site we're programming in the company has things like you said, custom dashboard, you can show dashboard or parts of it depending if the user is logged or depending on the user permissions. You can store that things (number of comments today, views,articles...) in the object user data... I don't feel that you cannot customize that kind of things. We use jquery,javascript,ajax,bootstrap,custom css....

Answer (score 0):

Using a framework like Django will start you right into developing your application. They you intend to work will cost you years of work to create your own web application infrastructure without getting anything useful.

The strength of Python is the availability of countless modules, packages and frameworks to build upon. Without there you will be getting nowhere.